# Вывести весь словарь с его именем и исходным форматированием

Tags: python, словари, dict

```
from pprint import pprint

site = {
    'html': {
        'head': {
            'title': 'Куплю/продам телефон недорого'
        },
        'body': {
            'h2': 'У нас самая низкая цена на iphone',
            'div': 'Купить',
            'p': 'продать'
        }
    }
}


def find_key(struct, key, meaning):
    if key in struct:
        struct[key] = meaning
        return site

    for sub_struct in struct.values():
        if isinstance(sub_struct, dict):
            result = find_key(sub_struct, key, meaning)
            if result:
                return site


number_sites = int(input('Сколько сайтов: '))
for _ in range(number_sites):
    product_name = input('Введите название продукта для нового сайта: ')
    key = {'title': f'Куплю/продам {product_name} недорого', 'h2': f'У нас самая низкая цена на {product_name}'}
    for i in key:
        find_key(site, i, key[i])

    print(f'Сайт для {product_name}:')
    pprint(site)
```

Результат выполнения кода нужно вывести в соответствии с ниже приложенным примером и данным форматированием вывода:

```
site = {
    'html': {
        'head': {
            'title': 'Куплю/продам телефон недорого'
        },
        'body': {
            'h2': 'У нас самая низкая цена на iphone',
            'div': 'Купить',
            'p': 'продать'
        }
    }
}
```

Json не катит, так как это статический кусок кода с которым нужно работать.
Говорят как-то можно организовать с помощью рекурсии.

Comment: Вот тут пример класса-форматтера: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26209900/4752653 . Результат на вашем примере: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTmrR.png

Comment: Вопрос на самом деле интересный. То что дает стандартный модуль pprint - довольно своеобразный способ форматирования. Странно, что до сих пор никто не впилил туда json-образный вариант форматирования.

Comment: я не знаю :( только начал осваивать. у меня получилось добиться вывода с форматированием, но вывод не полный - название списка не выводится и остальные закрывающие скобки

Comment: Имя переменной и присваивание сами добавляйте в начало. Со скобками и так все в порядке, не знаю что вы еще туда хотите добавить.

Comment: Я имел ввиду свой вариант. А ваша подсказка - да, работает шикарно. Спасибо большое. Как вап + репу поставить, что-то не могу найти

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
from pprint import pprint

import io

site = {
    'html': {
        'head': {
            'title': 'Куплю/продам телефон недорого'
        },
        'body': {
            'h2': 'У нас самая низкая цена на iphone',
            'div': 'Купить',
            'p': 'продать'
        }
    }
}


def find_key(struct, key, meaning):
    if key in struct:
        struct[key] = meaning
        return site

    for sub_struct in struct.values():
        if isinstance(sub_struct, dict):
            result = find_key(sub_struct, key, meaning)
            if result:
                return site


number_sites = int(input('Сколько сайтов: '))
for _ in range(number_sites):
    product_name = input('Введите название продукта для нового сайта: ')
    key = {'title': f'Куплю/продам {product_name} недорого', 'h2': f'У нас самая низкая цена на {product_name}'}
    for i in key:
        find_key(site, i, key[i])

    print(f'Сайт для {product_name}:')


buf = io.StringIO()

pprint(site, stream=buf)

output = "site = " + buf.getvalue()

print(
    output
)
```

output:

```latex
site = {'html': {'body': {'div': 'Купить',
                   'h2': 'У нас самая низкая цена на InMySite',
                   'p': 'продать'},
          'head': {'title': 'Куплю/продам InMySite недорого'}}}
```

#### UPD:

```py
data = json.dumps(
    site,
    ensure_ascii=False,
    indent=4
)
print(
    # следите чтобы в строковых значениях не попадались знаки двойных кавычек, 
    # а так же избегайте значений True, False, None
    "site = " + data.replace('"', "'")
)
```

```json
site = {
    'html': {
        'head': {
            'title': 'Куплю/продам InMySite недорого'
        },
        'body': {
            'h2': 'У нас самая низкая цена на InMySite',
            'div': 'Купить',
            'p': 'продать'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: почти, форматирование не соблюдено при выводе, нужное. все скобки в один ряд ```недорого'}}}```

Comment: @3Vw поменяйте в строковом форматированном json `"` на `'`  и будет Вам счастье.

Comment: @3Vw, а вообще, генерация фалов кода это онанизм чистой воды (ИМХО)

Comment: согласен, но не я это придумал. счастье не приходит :( не совсем понимаю про json и "

Comment: @3Vw обновил ответ

Comment: @3Vw, хотя по правде абсолютно не понятно чем Вам json в чистом виде не угодил. Словарь читается абсолютно нормально что с двойными кавычками что с динарными. Разница лишь В значениях true (True) false (False) и null (None) так что если они не попадаются то можно json использовать как мне кажется

Comment: пушка, то что доктор прописал. json тоже нормально и строчек меньше. но он выводит лишнее значения, дополнительные скобки, а нужно организовать 100 % сходство, еще раз спасибо